# Edit a Excel file in Sharepoint programmatically

Tags: node.js, excel, azure, sharepoint

I'm trying to read/edit a SharePoint protected Excel file using NodeJS,

I have a user & password that have access to that file.
I used `node-sp-auth`, `request-promise` & `gd-sprest`, I was only able to get the URI of the file but I couldn't do much with it.

is it at least feasible? any other library suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

**To resolve this issue, I recommend you to use one of 2 approaches options:**

**Option 01**: Develop a Web Service and share the captured SharePoint excel file with a resource like a base64 with this Web Service and on this Web Service develop the rules where will edit this Excel File; or,

**Option 02**: Using C# Programming and using CSOM Library, that will be more easy to get and edit you Excel file in one solution code;

Comment: Thanks Antonio, problem isn't to manipulate the excel file, but it's to download it, I'm not sure I can. Also better if I could do a live edit, using Sharepoint's APIs for instance

Answer (score 0):

For Office 365 you need to read the [Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/excel-update-range-format?tabs=javascript) documentation and use [@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client)
package.